# VLOOKUP Excel formula for multiple colums

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two columns "A" and "C" containing names of people. Columns "B" and "D" contain their birth dates. How can I make 1 data validation table for columns A & C without having to make them in one long column?

```
A          B        C         D
John    3.12.14    Tony    9.4.14
```

Display will be: Tony (in one cell); 9.4.14 in the the next. (Say col. E and F)

Altogether there are 4 columns for the vlookup formula.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps use `IFERROR`?

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E1, A:B, 2, 0), VLOOKUP(E1, C:D, 2, 0))
```

Or if the dates are not text but actually values in date format, you should be able to use this:

```
=SUMIF(A:C, E1, B:D)
```

Comment: Seems like it'd work, should those `0` be `FALSE`?

Comment: @Raystafarian `0` is equivalent to `FALSE` in excel, as much as `1` is equivalent to `TRUE`. You can do `=1*TRUE` and get 1 as result, or do `=1*FALSE` to get 0 as result in excel.